# Replacing All Data in a Table within pptx (not 1 cell)

Tags: python-pptx

I would like to replace all data in a table in the existing ppt slide (not just one cell).  I know what my shape id is and I found a solution ([Python Pptx - Modify Existing Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841229/python-pptx-modify-existing-table)) that solves for replacement of 1 cell in a table:
Presentation('yourpowerpoint.pptx').slides[0].shapes[6].table.cell(0,0).text= 'Pina Colada'

However, I have two additional questions related to replacing data in a table:
1) How can I replace all data of the table at once instead of one cell at a time?
2) When I replace data in a cell, I noticed that size of the font, centering, and color of the font change.  How can I keep the font as it is in the exiting ppt table and only replace values?

Comment: What data do you want to put into the table? Doesn't it have different values for each cell? What benefit are you expecting from avoiding cell-by-cell updates?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and question.  I was planning to insert data from a DataFrame.  On the second thought, cell by cell update is not too difficult because it is possible to write a loop for it.  Please ignore my question if there is no direct way to insert Dataframe values into ppt table.

Comment: @Sveta - Did you manage to solve this problem? I also face a similar issue where replacement is successful but font size, centering etc is all changed. Is this something that you would be able to help me with ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73202432/python-pptx-access-table-cell-properties-and-apply-it-back-during-replace